# Using different levels of interfaces

Tags: go, interface

I'm trying to organize my code using interfaces in Go.

I have 2 sources of data: FTP and API. In each source, I have several structs that make the logic vary depending on the case.

In this question, I will omit API and stick with FTP.

My problem comes from the impossibility to say: *FTPAcq is also an Acquisition*

If `FetchMeters()`, when I do `ftp.Decrypt(nil)` I would like ftp to be "compatible" with `FTPAcq`

Here is my code:

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/dutchcoders/goftp"
    log "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
    "os"
)

type Acquisition interface {
    FetchMeters() ([]Meter, error)
    Name() string
}

type FTPAcq interface {
    Unzip(file string) string
    Decrypt(file string) string
}

//type APIAcq interface {
//  FetchMeter(meterID string) (Meter, error)
//}

func main() {
    var acqs []Acquisition
    ftp, err := NewFTPDriver(os.Getenv("FTP_USER"), os.Getenv("FTP_PASSWD"), os.Getenv("FTP_ADDR"), os.Getenv("FTP_PORT"))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    ftp1 := NewFTPDriverSGE(*ftp)
    ftp2 := NewFTPDriverTA(*ftp)
    acqs = append(acqs, ftp1, ftp2)
    for _, acq := range acqs {
        tmpMeters, err := acq.FetchMeters()
        if err != nil {
            log.Warn(acq.Name(), " got error :", err)
        }
        log.Info(tmpMeters)
    }
}

type Meter struct {
    ID          string
    OperationID string
    Unit        string
}

//FtpSGE is a implementation of acquisition Interface (see driver.go)
type FTP struct {
    Username string
    Password string
    Url      string
    Port     string
    client   *goftp.FTP
}
type FTPSGE struct {
    FTP
}
type FTPTA struct {
    FTP
}

func (f FTPSGE) Unzip(path string) []string {
    return nil
}
func (f FTPTA) Unzip(path string) []string {
    return nil
}

func (f FTPSGE) Decrypt(path string) []string {
    return nil
}

func (f FTPTA) Decrypt(path string) []string {
    return nil
}

func (ftp FTP) FetchMeters() ([]Meter, error) {
    log.Info(ftp.Name(), " is running")
    files := ftp.Download(nil)
    files = ftp.Decrypt("") // I have several implementation of Decrypt
    files = ftp.Unzip("")   // I have several implementation of Unzip
    log.Info(files)
    return nil, nil
}

func (ftp FTP) Name() string {
    panic("FTP ")
}

func (ftp FTP) Download(files []string) []string {
    panic("implement me")
}

func NewFTPDriver(user, password, url, port string) (*FTP, error) {
    var err error
    ftp := &FTP{
        Username: user,
        Password: password,
        Url:      url,
        Port:     port,
    }
    if ftp.client, err = goftp.Connect(url + ":" + port); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    if err = ftp.client.Login(user, password); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return ftp, nil
}
func NewFTPDriverSGE(f FTP) *FTPSGE {
    return &FTPSGE{f}
}

func NewFTPDriverTA(f FTP) *FTPTA {
    return &FTPTA{f}
}
```

In my case, I get:

```
ftp.Decrypt undefined (type FTP has no field or method Decrypt)
```

How should I do?

Comment: You're trying to call `Decrypt` on a type which doesn't have that method. You can only call methods on values of types that actually have those methods.

Comment: Note that this has nothing to do with interfaces. You could delete them both and you'd still get the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FTP` does **not** implement `FTPAcq`. It implements only `Acquisition`. It doesn't even have `Decrypt()` as a method, interface or not.

`FTPSGE` and `FTPTA` implement `FTPAcq`, but they are **not** the same type as `FTP`.

I don't know what you're trying to accomplish, but perhaps something to try is *embedding* `FTP` in `FTPSGE` and `FTPTA`. This gives those 2 types the fields and methods of the embedded type and still allows you to define additional methods on those types (the methods for `FTPAcq` in your case).

For example

```golang
type FTPSGE {
    FTP
}
// OR
type FTPSGE {
    *FTP
}
```

Which you then create as so: `x := FTPSGE{ftp1}`. Keep in mind that this will create a **copy** of `ftp1` inside `x`. If `ftp1` is type `FTP` (not a pointer), the entire struct gets copied. If `ftp1` is type `*FTP` (a pointer, which seems to be what you're using), the pointer is copied and `x.FTP` still points to the same data as `ftp1`.

This means `FTPSGE` will implement both `Acquisition` and `FTPAcq`.

You'll have to be careful of whether or not interfaces are implemented on the value or pointer: `func (a A) Something()` vs `func (a *A) Somthing()`.

Here is some reading on methods, interfaces, and embedding.

1. https://www.ardanlabs.com/blog/2014/05/methods-interfaces-and-embedded-types.html
2. https://travix.io/type-embedding-in-go-ba40dd4264df
3. https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html (and lots of other info)